# Finding condition expected values over triangle region.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that X and Y are distributed uniformly on the triangle with endpoints (-2,0), (0,2) and (2,0). Find $E[Y^2|X=1]$

**What I've tried**

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{Area} = \frac{1}{(\frac{1*4*2}{2})}=\frac{1}{4}$$

when $-2 < x < 0$ then $0<y<2+x$

when $0<x<2$ then $0<y<2-x$

It's been a while since I've taken calc III and worked with double integrals, but I think this needs to be split into two parts (although this solution hasn't worked for me yet)

$p_X(1) = \int_{0}^{2+x} \frac{1}{8}dy$ = $\frac{1}{3}$

$p_X(1) = \int_{0}^{2-x} \frac{1}{8}dy = 1$

E[Y^2|X=1] = $\int_{0}^{2+x} \frac{y^2}{8}dy$+$\int_{0}^{2-x} y^2dy$

I haven't bothered to solve for this, because the answer will depend on x, which is clearly wrong because X=1. However integrating between 0 and 4 seems to ignore the issue of the slope of the line. How can I take into account both of those conditions to arrive at the correct answer?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I recommend that you identify one or two solid probability definitions or formulas to use.  The equations you are writing lack motivation and seem very strange.  Perhaps you are trying to jump to an answer by guessing.  But you also seem comfortable with "$1/3=1$," and you should not be comfortable with that.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the range of $Y$ when $X=1$.   Since the atoms are uniformly distributed over the triangle, then they are also distributed uniformly over this line.   The conditional density will then be obvious.

$$\mathsf E(Y^2\mid X=1) = \int_0^? y^2\; f_{Y\mid X{=}1}(y) \operatorname d y$$